Is it possible that fundamental truths about the origins of our reality will never be discovered?

What was before The Big Bang?

How has life started?

How did intelligent life start?


In philosophy there are two polar extreme views:
a. Nothing exists (reliably) outside our personal imagination.
b. Everything is real in the physical world, but our personal consciousness is just a small reflection of this reality.
My question applies to the second point of view.

The answer to "is it possible we will never discover the fundamental truths" that seems like obviously yes, regardless of if discovering them is possible--we could all get struck by a meteor and die?

It sure is. Humanity may well be wiped out in the next 100 years, it came close in 1962 already. Our perception or cognitive apparatus may well permanently screen off aspects of reality even if we last longer. But what is the question besides the triviality?

@Kaia - This question is about fundamental truth, not about an ant sitting on a leaf.

We have plenty of indications about how life started, and we have much stronger evidence about how intelligence emerged. Asking what happened before the Big Bang is in part like asking what happened "before" time began (it's unclear if that question even makes sense) and it's in part like asking if we can make/discover a material stronger than the strongest known material - you're asking what's beyond the limits of our knowledge, but if we discover a new thing, that becomes the new limit and one can just ask what's beyond that - the question doesn't seem as significant as people seem to think.

@NotThatGuy - You are trying to say that nothing exists outside the reach of our limited brains. And even if something does exist, we don't care about it?

@TheMatrixEquation-balance you asked about the "everything is real in the physical world, but our consciousness is just a small reflection of this reality". Isn't that "the ant's view"?

Intelligence is not the issue.  Causal processes could create intelligence.  It is consciousness that is the mystery.

@TheMatrixEquation-balance "You are trying to say that nothing exists outside the reach of our limited brains" - not at all. I'm just saying the current limits are the current limits. Those limits were different in the past, so it's not unreasonable to suspect that those limits would or may be different in the future. There may be firm limits we can't go beyond, and there may be some reasons to think we found those limits in some places (like with the Big Bang), but we could be wrong about that - it's hard to know what we can't know.

It seems that you are trying to find an alternative to theism. I don't know of any successes in that area, but maybe someone here does.

@ScottRowe - "I don't know of any successes in that area" - in my view, all you have to do is to pick a good book. A great story (admired by generations), even though imaginative, will be closer to truth than sophist demagogy.


     The child is father of the man;
And I could wish my days to be
     Bound each to each by natural piety

As you can see (and feel?) above, the true poet is delicately balanced:

between natural and theological
between adult and child
between subjective and objective povs.

The poem — here its the great English poet William Wordsworth — will repay study in more detail. For here I will choose few parts, starting with a different one

A slumber did my spirit seal;
       I had no human fears:
She seemed a thing that could not feel
       The touch of earthly years.
No motion has she now, no force;
       She neither hears nor sees;
Rolled round in earth's diurnal course,
       With rocks, and stones, and trees.

The closing of the first

The Clouds that gather round the setting sun
Do take a sober colouring from an eye
That hath kept watch o'er man's mortality;
Another race hath been, and other palms are won.
Thanks to the human heart by which we live,
Thanks to its tenderness, its joys, and fears,
To me the meanest flower that blows can give
Thoughts that do often lie too deep for tears.

A more direct answer to your question would be from Jung:

He who looks outward dreams;
He who looks inward awakens

IOW meditate!
(whatever form or system makes sense to you)

Since some literalists want a more literal answer:
A good 3 centuries ago, Kant settled what he was confident enough to proclaim was his ‘Copernican Revolution:’ It is the representation that makes the object possible not the object that makes the representation possible:

Nothing which is intuited in space is a thing in itself, and space is not a form which belongs as a property to things; but objects are quite unknown to us in themselves, and what we call outward objects are nothing else but mere representations of our sensibility, whose form is space, but whose real correlated thing in itself is not known by means of these representations, nor ever can be, but respecting which, in experience, no inquiry is ever made.
Immanuel Kant — CPR

So what things are in their fundamental reality is either:

An ever unknowable problem
Or else a meaningless question

In Kantian language we are ever stuck in the phenomena — ‘the representations of our sensibility’, the phenomena, we can never know the noumena.
In that sense Kant (like Plato) prefigures (your favorite!) the Matrix: Being wired in(to) the matrix it is a hopeless exercise to struggle to get out... except on its terms.
This harks back to all the multitude of eastern teachings which in different ways assert: He who chooses God chooses because God chose him. vide.

Sufi AL-Hallaj: When I saw my Lord with the eye of the heart, I said, 'Who are You?' He said, 'You'
Bhagavad Gita: You cannot see Me with your present eyes. Therefore, I give you divine eyes. Behold My mystic opulence!


Ultimately, poets, philosophers, scientists, all play the same role: to make human animals a little bit more human-like. In this endeavor, conservative thinking and progressive thinking carry their part.

@TheMatrixEquation-balance I actually thought of starting my answer with Gurdjieff There can be more difference between one man and another than between a man and a cockroach. But then, leftist PC has an inflated premium these days

Not everybody can start thinking outside the box (literally).

On the contrary @TheMatrixEquation-balance. Everyone slides continually between 4 levels of language, therefore understanding

I remember a conference from the physicist Lawrence Krauss that can exemplify a true fact we could never have known about, were the circumstances different.
He spoke about the expansion of the universe and how it's accelerating. At some point galaxies will drift from one another so fast the light they emit won't be able to reach each other (basically, space will expand faster than light can cross it).
This means, astronomers of this era won't be able to see other galaxies, they will think the universe is made of but one such structure, and there's a whole lot of things they won't be able to understand about the universe (including the fact that it's expanding).
It raises the question: what other fundamental phenomenon are we unable to observe because we are in the wrong place or time, if any?

Right, things probably looked pretty interesting billions of years ago. Maybe we could have seen the cosmic background radiation, or felt it.

@Rushi To be clear, that's not what this answer suggests at all.  This is about the nature of the observable universe and how it is changing with time.  The only reason we know that nature or the changes it is undergoing are the physicists you deride.  The big rip is not regarded as a likely outcome in the universe's future.  Finally, The God Delusion was written by a biologist and is a philosophical and political work, not primarily a scientific one.

@JasonPatterson I would have assumed that observanle universe presumes an observer. Evidently this answer and you follow your high pries...  sorry, physicists in ignoring that issue.

@ScottRowe The CMB was predicted by Alpher and Herman about 15 years before its accidental discovery by Penzias and Wilson.  They realized that when it was released it absolutely would have been visible.  The peak of its spectrum (a ~3000K blackbody) would have been in the near IR, but it still would have had significant visible red and orange components.  It would have been amazing to see, but also pretty quickly fatal, unfortunately, as literally the entire universe was that average temperature at that point in time.

@Rushi calling people clueless while demonstrating you didn't understand a word of what I wrote is funny. Maybe keep in check your own eagerness to proselytize before pointing at people who put in the actual research work so that you can have an internet to ramble on...

@Rushi I didn't see the original comment, but if you don't like 'observable' universe, you could substitute "within the light cone" or something to get around that meddlesome observer. We can worship cause and effect instead, right? Entropy? "What do you want on your Tombstone" (pizza)?

I dont see any plausible way to rule it out, so in general I think the answer to the question in your title is "Yes".
The three questions you provided are ones where our current state of knowledge (and even our reliable methods of building knowledge) can only speculate on those answers.  There's no reason to expect that in the future we will come up with a foolproof method of verifying past events.  Therefore, there's no reason to rule out the possibility that we will never answer those questions.
There's also more trivial reasons, like those mentioned in the comments.  It is possible for all humans to be wiped out in practically any time frame, before we could answer those questions.
It is also possible that the answers to those questions cannot be comprehended by humans, so in that case it also wouldnt be possible for us to answer those questions due to fundamental limits of our comprehension.
You could probably come up with more reasons, but really it only takes one for the answer to be "yes".

You are thinking from the ant's point of view. Of course, anything is possible from that vantage point. But try to think from the Creator's point of view and the purpose he put into the Big Bang.

@TheMatrixEquation-balance I'm talking from a human point of view because it is the only one available to us.  I dont see why I should think from the "creators" point of view, because it is also possible that no such creator exists.

"I'm talking from a human point of view because it is the only one available to us" - Imagine you are sitting in the theater, watching the performance and trying to ask who wrote the original script. Would you be surprised if they told you that you could only ask about what you could see on the stage?

@TheMatrixEquation-balance That doesnt make sense as an analogy here.  In a theatre you are going to see a show that you know was written by someone and that is external to the events on stage.  We dont know how life in general came to be, it doesnt make sense to just assume there is some creator.

@TheMatrixEquation-balance So your argument is that I lack imagination because I'm capable of imagining a situation that you cannot imagine?  That makes absolutely no sense.

You only offered denial. It is not the same as alternative vision (imagination).

@TheMatrixEquation-balance I'm answering the question, which is about the possibility that those questions cant be answered.  The question isnt about theism, why would you expect me to go over arguments against theism here?  Your comments are essentially nonsense.

@TheMatrixEquation-balance maybe it's just tone being difficult to convey through text, but some of your responses strike me as rude or dismissive; is there a way you can try to understand people's arguments and explain your own without saying people are "like ants" or "have no imagination" etc?

@Kaia - I agree. I am sorry.

@JMac - "The question isnt about theism" - this is what triggers me. When practical philosophical questions are aggressively denied and left to theism to deal with.

@TheMatrixEquation-balance What is aggressive about how this was dealt with?  The problem is that the question really isn't that practical philosophically.  The way the question is worded, it's easy to come up with possible ways those questions dont have answers.  That is not the same as saying "it's not possible those questions will be answered".

@TheMatrixEquation-balance I can imagine a creator, I just don't see any good reason to think one exists. And if this reality had a creator, I can also imagine what traits they might have, and if given some traits of a creator, I can also imagine what type of reality they might create - many theists propose a creator with traits that are at odds with what we'd expect to see in this reality (and that are at odds with other parts of their own theology).

@NotThatGuy -  Philosophers refusing to take on philosophical questions does not mean they believe in the absence of the metaphysical (a pure physical world).  They just conveniently put it out of scope.

@TheMatrixEquation-balance Who's "refusing to take on philosophical questions"? Someone rejecting claims about the supernatural doesn't mean they refuse to take on related questions, and someone asserting that they have the answer isn't better than saying "I don't know" when we don't know. We'll know what happened "before" the Big Bang when we know it, if we can know it, if that question even makes sense. Abstract philosophy has not given us answers about the origin of stuff, only guesses, whereas science gave us the answer of the Big Bang, among many others, and will continue giving answers.

@Rushi I have no idea what contradictions you think you're seeing. I'd suggest trying to read what I wrote more carefully. (Taking issue with the name of a scientific theory does nothing to refute any of the evidence supporting it.)

@NotThatGuy Is not the big bang the event/point/time of the origin of the entire (physical) universe according to current astrophysics fashionability?  Also do check Lemaitre's profession when he was not professing astrophysics.  Anyone who pretends that the bigbang is not Genesis-1 timedistorted & modernized, is just playing the ostrich

@Rushi I still have no idea what contradictions you think you're seeing. I also have no idea what Lemaitre's other activities has to do with anything (unless you have some deeply twisted and deformed view of science, where it's no longer about evidence, explanatory power and experimentation, but instead about dogma and presupposition). And pretending that the Bible has any scientific merits whatsoever is little more than delusion: you're just looking at what science produced after the fact, and bashing words with a hammer until their bent and broken enough for you to see some similarities.

Stuff that is real but is unobservable is not really reliably real, e.g.

An outstanding characteristic of modern physics is the application of
the principle that only that which is observable is significant. ...
the followers of Einstein maintained that if the physical world were
regarded as including entities or conceptions which were unobservable
either directly or indirectly, there was no criterion for
distinguishing the real from the unreal. (Nature, 1937)

So what we can reliably talk about tends towards the limits of knowledge and reason.  Admittedly this is unsatisfactory as regards for instance, knowing what is in unobservable space. Nevertheless, all is not lost. Since it can be demonstrated that the contradiction of causality and spontaneity confounds reason, the accessible starting point is necessarily moved back to personal existence which brings the perspective into its proper orientation. From there we can comprehend finitude, beginnings and endings.
Re. "truths about the origins of our reality will never be discovered?"
Thus one might consider, "how has reality originated for me?" Childhood.

"how has reality originated for me?" - The childhood of the ant observing the world from the leaf. This is a small room where philosophers locked themselves in. For the rest of the world there is such a thing as imagination.

"Stuff that is real but is unobservable is not really reliably real" - There are plenty of entities considered real in science that we can't observe, but we can observe the effects of them.  And then we make guess about what they are like based on those effects.  And our guesses change over time.

@ConiferTravis Being able to see their effects is the same as observable in the long run.

@TheMatrixEquation-balance You may imagine all you like but philosophy tends to like some rigour.

Not sure if you're putting the Nature quote approvingly or otherwise.  To me it's trivially circular: Observable is real;   Real is observable

@Rushi I do like the turn of phrase in the Nature article.  However, I think Dingle's motivation was one of reluctant acceptance of the physical or practical unobservability of absolute time.  In other words, he still believes in absolute time.  If he had perhaps understood the logical unobservability of absolute time (which seems to be the actual case) then he might have given a different lecture.

We could do an experiment using an interferometer to prove the existence of absolute time, like the Michaelson Morley experiment for the Luminiferous Ether... Probably with the same result, being denied by the adherents (who did the experiment) to the grave. "It is really just an interesting psychological phenomenon."

@ScottRowe As I understand it the demonstration is straightforward. Astronauts in different frames can pre-calculate according to their time dilation so that from one astronaut's point of view they could all snap their fingers absolutely simultaneously, (not just so it looks simultaneous from the light received, but actually so). However, the finger snaps wouldn't be simultaneous from the other astronauts' perspectives. Each one's arrangement for synchronised finger snaps would be different. Everyone has their own set of simultaneous events. Presentism is relative! adding nuance for being.

Re. time dilation. It's not rocket science. ;-)
